# How should I care for my  Calendula?

Tags: indoors, flowers, fertilizer

I have a small *Calendula* plant indoors and it is growing quite well. However, can I care for the plant better by following any specific care instructions? At the moment I'm just giving it plenty of tap water and sunlight, but no extra feed.

Should I add a supplement to the water, use rain water instead of tap water, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never grown calendula indoors, but I've found them to be relatively undemanding when grown outside in soil of reasonable fertility.

Make sure the pot is big enough and has sufficient drainage.

If you didn't plant it into potting soil that has any kind of added fertilizer, or you didn't use any compost, then you may want a small amount of some low-analysis balanced organic fertilizer once a month or so.

Be careful not to overwater.

If it's growing well, and continues to grow well, you're probably already giving it what it needs. If the plant's health starts to decline, then make sure you aren't overwatering, and consider adding a *small amount* of fertilizer. (It won't take much for a single plant in a small pot -- follow package directions.)

Comment: Can you recommend a fertilizer? I've moved the plant to a more shaded area and it seems to be flourishing, but there may be some other variables at play.

Comment: I can't recommend a specific fertilizer. You might try asking for a low-analysis liquid houseplant fertilizer at your local garden center.

Comment: Would the fertilizer that I described in my other question work? http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/can-i-use-an-npk-compund-fertilizer-on-herbs

Comment: I don't know much about citrus, so I don't know what that fertilizer would have that makes it good for citrus.