# Can I use an NPK compund fertilizer on herbs?

Tags: plant-health, fertilizer, herbs, basil, citrus

I have some "Low nutrient NPK compound fertilizer" which is sold as *Citrus Food* left over from a Calamondin tree which has sadly passed away.

Can I use this fertilizer on my herbs? They are basil, oregano, thyme, parsley, coriander, chives.

It has nothing on the bottle which says you shouldn't use it on plants that aren't citrus fruit-baring, but will it benefit my herbs much even if I do go ahead and feed them with it?

Comment: Are your herbs growing in the garden or in containers?

Comment: @Eric Nitardy they are in containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, should be fine, citrus fertilizers usually have extra micronutrients, like chromium and copper.